# How to upload output blob to a server?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, upload, blob

Trying to upload a blob data from browser, there is input and output in console. I am using the Image-Compressor from (https://github.com/fengyuanchen/compressorjs).

All working fine, but the problem with understanding hot to "catch" this blob and send to a server.

I tried out this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="button" value="Проверить" onclick="myAjax()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var file = "outputURL"; // instance of File
function myAjax() {
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'upload.php',
  data: file,
  contentType: 'application/my-binary-type', // set accordingly
  processData: false
});
}
</script>
```

upload.php:

```
$fname = "11" . ".wav";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "/" . $fname);
```

The idea of this to have some button on html which will upload the output compressed image to a server.
I've tried out also several other examples, but main problem - I am don understanding how to handle a blob.

Here is my console output:

```
Input:  FilelastModified: 1548655773101lastModifiedDate: Mon Jan 28 2019 11:09:33 GMT+0500 {}name: "IMG_20160705_165257565.jpg"size: 3233327type: "image/jpeg"webkitRelativePath: ""__proto__: File

Output:  BloblastModified: 1572005360479lastModifiedDate: Fri Oct 25 2019 17:09:20 GMT+0500  {}name: "IMG_20160705_165257565.jpg"size: 1625797type: "image/jpeg"__proto__: Blob
```

Please help to understand how to handle with blobs data in browser.

Comment: `FormData` can easily handle blobs, with the [`append` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) you can add them directly, and then you just specify the FormData instance as the `data` you are sending with your AJAX request.

Comment: Can somebody give a some example based on details what I gave. For the advise - thanks. Will educate myself.

Comment: Ok. I can help. What type of server page are you using? PHP, ASP.net, if you give some details, I can help to give you an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is fully working example with how to upload a blob:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<script>
function init() {
  var form = document.getElementById('f');
  if(form) {
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      if(form.ajax.checked) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        for(var i=0; i<form.length; i++) {
          if(form[i].type == 'file') {
            var files = form[i].files;
            var blob = files[0].slice(0, files[0].size, files[0].type);
            formData.append(form[i].name, blob, files[0].name);
          }
          else {
            formData.append(form[i].name, form[i].value);
          }
        }
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
            // what do I do here?
            // is it
            // window.location = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
            // or should it be
            // document.write(responseText);
            // or even
            // document.close(); document.open(); document.write(xhr.responseText);
            // or?
          }
        };
        xhr.open('POST', form.action, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }, false);
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='init()'>
<?php
  if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>name: '.$_FILES['file']['name'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>type: '.$_FILES['file']['type'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>size: '.$_FILES['file']['size'].'</li>';
    echo '<li>upload type: '.$_POST['ajax'].'</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
    echo "<a href='http://localhost/test.php'>reset</a>";
  }
  else {
?>
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' id='f' method='POST'>
<input name='file' type='file'/>
ajax: <input name='ajax' type='checkbox'/>
<input type='submit'/>
</form>
<?php
  }
?>
</body>
</html>
```